# Yii 2: Module class not found

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-modules

In the **backend/config/main** file, there is a reference to the module class:

```
'modules' => [
    'cropk' => [
        'class' => 'app\modules\cropk\CropK',
    ]
],
```

In the **vendor/xxx/cropk** directory, there is the following class **CropK**:

```
namespace app\modules\cropk;

class CropK extends \yii\base\Module {

    public function init() {
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

The **vendor/xxx/cropk/controllers/DefaultController**:

```
namespace app\modules\cropk\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller {
    public function actionIndex() {
        return $this->render('index');
    }
}
```

But when I access the URL **http://admin.cropk.dev/cropk**, I get this error:

*Class app\modules\cropk\CropK does not exist*

Can't I put the module outside of the backend directory? How can I do that?

Comment: When the module was in the **backend/modules**, it was working. As I wish to create a more generic module, I have transferred the entire module to the **vendor/xxx** directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normaly the module is indicated in this way

```
'modules' => [
    'moduleName' => [
        'class' => 'vendor\vendorName\moduleName\Module',
```

and rename your module class in `Module` and not `Cropk`

This is a sample of Module.php

```
    /*
     *
     *  */

    namespace vendor\xxx\modulename;

    use \yii\base\Module as BaseModule;

    /**
     *
     */
    class Module extends BaseModule
    {
        public $controllerNamespace = 'vendor\xxx\modulename\controllers';

        const VERSION = '1.0.0-dev';

        public function init()
        {
            parent::init();

            // custom initialization code goes here
        }
    }
```

Comment: My daily limit has been reached.